# Same error message multiple times via Wordpress error log

Tags: php, wordpress, error-handling

I'm getting the same error log message multiple times when a page is just loaded once and was wondering if this was normal for Wordpress? If not, how do I trouble shoot this? 
The following is a snippet from my error log. The first 5 lines reproduce themselves 5 times for 1 page load. This can't be right, right? Thanks!

```
    [22-Aug-2017 19:18:11 UTC] PHP Notice:  Use of undefined constant ‘TwitterOAuth’ - assumed '‘TwitterOAuth’' in /filedir
    [22-Aug-2017 19:18:11 UTC] PHP Notice:  The called constructor method for WP_Widget in Woothemes_Widget_Testimonials is <strong>deprecated</strong> since version 4.3.0! Use <pre>__construct()</pre> instead. in /filedir
    [22-Aug-2017 19:18:11 UTC] PHP Notice:  The called constructor method for WP_Widget in Affiliates_Registration_Widget is <strong>deprecated</strong> since version 4.3.0! Use <pre>__construct()</pre> instead. in /filedir
    [22-Aug-2017 19:18:11 UTC] PHP Notice:  The called constructor method for WP_Widget in Etheme_Twitter_Widget is <strong>deprecated</strong> since version 4.3.0! Use <pre>__construct()</pre> instead. in /filedir
    [22-Aug-2017 19:18:11 UTC] PHP Notice:  The called constructor method for WP_Widget in Etheme_Recent_Posts_Widget is <strong>deprecated</strong> since version 4.3.0! Use <pre>__construct()</pre> instead. in /filedir
    [22-Aug-2017 19:18:11 UTC] PHP Notice:  The called constructor method for WP_Widget in Etheme_Flickr_Widget is <strong>deprecated</strong> since version 4.3.0! Use <pre>__construct()</pre> instead. in /filedir
[22-Aug-2017 19:18:11 UTC] PHP Notice:  Use of undefined constant ‘TwitterOAuth’ - assumed '‘TwitterOAuth’' in /filedir
    [22-Aug-2017 19:18:11 UTC] PHP Notice:  The called constructor method for WP_Widget in Woothemes_Widget_Testimonials is <strong>deprecated</strong> since version 4.3.0! Use <pre>__construct()</pre> instead. in /filedir
    [22-Aug-2017 19:18:11 UTC] PHP Notice:  The called constructor method for WP_Widget in Affiliates_Registration_Widget is <strong>deprecated</strong> since version 4.3.0! Use <pre>__construct()</pre> instead. in /filedir
    [22-Aug-2017 19:18:11 UTC] PHP Notice:  The called constructor method for WP_Widget in Etheme_Twitter_Widget is <strong>deprecated</strong> since version 4.3.0! Use <pre>__construct()</pre> instead. in /filedir
    [22-Aug-2017 19:18:11 UTC] PHP Notice:  The called constructor method for WP_Widget in Etheme_Recent_Posts_Widget is <strong>deprecated</strong> since version 4.3.0! Use <pre>__construct()</pre> instead. in /filedir
    [22-Aug-2017 19:18:11 UTC] PHP Notice:  The called constructor method for WP_Widget in Etheme_Flickr_Widget is <strong>deprecated</strong> since version 4.3.0! Use <pre>__construct()</pre> instead. in /filedir
[22-Aug-2017 19:18:11 UTC] PHP Notice:  Use of undefined constant ‘TwitterOAuth’ - assumed '‘TwitterOAuth’' in /filedir
    [22-Aug-2017 19:18:11 UTC] PHP Notice:  The called constructor method for WP_Widget in Woothemes_Widget_Testimonials is <strong>deprecated</strong> since version 4.3.0! Use <pre>__construct()</pre> instead. in /filedir
    [22-Aug-2017 19:18:11 UTC] PHP Notice:  The called constructor method for WP_Widget in Affiliates_Registration_Widget is <strong>deprecated</strong> since version 4.3.0! Use <pre>__construct()</pre> instead. in /filedir
    [22-Aug-2017 19:18:11 UTC] PHP Notice:  The called constructor method for WP_Widget in Etheme_Twitter_Widget is <strong>deprecated</strong> since version 4.3.0! Use <pre>__construct()</pre> instead. in /filedir
    [22-Aug-2017 19:18:11 UTC] PHP Notice:  The called constructor method for WP_Widget in Etheme_Recent_Posts_Widget is <strong>deprecated</strong> since version 4.3.0! Use <pre>__construct()</pre> instead. in /filedir
    [22-Aug-2017 19:18:11 UTC] PHP Notice:  The called constructor method for WP_Widget in Etheme_Flickr_Widget is <strong>deprecated</strong> since version 4.3.0! Use <pre>__construct()</pre> instead. in /filedir
[22-Aug-2017 19:18:11 UTC] PHP Notice:  Use of undefined constant ‘TwitterOAuth’ - assumed '‘TwitterOAuth’' in /filedir
    [22-Aug-2017 19:18:11 UTC] PHP Notice:  The called constructor method for WP_Widget in Woothemes_Widget_Testimonials is <strong>deprecated</strong> since version 4.3.0! Use <pre>__construct()</pre> instead. in /filedir
    [22-Aug-2017 19:18:11 UTC] PHP Notice:  The called constructor method for WP_Widget in Affiliates_Registration_Widget is <strong>deprecated</strong> since version 4.3.0! Use <pre>__construct()</pre> instead. in /filedir
    [22-Aug-2017 19:18:11 UTC] PHP Notice:  The called constructor method for WP_Widget in Etheme_Twitter_Widget is <strong>deprecated</strong> since version 4.3.0! Use <pre>__construct()</pre> instead. in /filedir
    [22-Aug-2017 19:18:11 UTC] PHP Notice:  The called constructor method for WP_Widget in Etheme_Recent_Posts_Widget is <strong>deprecated</strong> since version 4.3.0! Use <pre>__construct()</pre> instead. in /filedir
    [22-Aug-2017 19:18:11 UTC] PHP Notice:  The called constructor method for WP_Widget in Etheme_Flickr_Widget is <strong>deprecated</strong> since version 4.3.0! Use <pre>__construct()</pre> instead. in /filedir
[22-Aug-2017 19:18:11 UTC] PHP Notice:  Use of undefined constant ‘TwitterOAuth’ - assumed '‘TwitterOAuth’' in /filedir
    [22-Aug-2017 19:18:11 UTC] PHP Notice:  The called constructor method for WP_Widget in Woothemes_Widget_Testimonials is <strong>deprecated</strong> since version 4.3.0! Use <pre>__construct()</pre> instead. in /filedir
    [22-Aug-2017 19:18:11 UTC] PHP Notice:  The called constructor method for WP_Widget in Affiliates_Registration_Widget is <strong>deprecated</strong> since version 4.3.0! Use <pre>__construct()</pre> instead. in /filedir
    [22-Aug-2017 19:18:11 UTC] PHP Notice:  The called constructor method for WP_Widget in Etheme_Twitter_Widget is <strong>deprecated</strong> since version 4.3.0! Use <pre>__construct()</pre> instead. in /filedir
    [22-Aug-2017 19:18:11 UTC] PHP Notice:  The called constructor method for WP_Widget in Etheme_Recent_Posts_Widget is <strong>deprecated</strong> since version 4.3.0! Use <pre>__construct()</pre> instead. in /filedir
    [22-Aug-2017 19:18:11 UTC] PHP Notice:  The called constructor method for WP_Widget in Etheme_Flickr_Widget is <strong>deprecated</strong> since version 4.3.0! Use <pre>__construct()</pre> instead. in /filedir
```

Comment: Igor Yavych already gave you the answer if you want to know more about it read: https://gist.github.com/chriscct7/d7d077afb01011b1839d

Answer (score 0):

Plugins/Theme that provide these widgets are outdated and are using old way of calling construct method. Update plugins and themes to their newest versions.

Comment: Thanks for your thoughts Igor. My question was not about why I was getting these error messages but why they all repeat 5 times. I only showed the 1 round of error messages, but imagine these all repeated 5 times each time a page is loaded

Comment: @bob_hardy1703 ah, I only saw 5 different errors when I answered your question. Do you have 5 sections like that at the exact same time with every page load? If these blocks of 5 are at different times, it just happens with every page load. If they are in fact at the exact same time, then it's weird. Do you have like 5 widget areas with them or something?

Answer (score 0):

You are not seeing repeated error messages, these error messages are all slightly different. The first message specifies that the method in `Woothemes_Widget_Testimonials` is deprecated, the second specifies that the method in `Affiliates_Registration_Widget` is deprecated, the third points to `Etheme_Twitter_Widget`, and so on.

The code will need to be fixed in each of the 5 places where it is specified in order for the messages to go away.

Comment: Sorry, I thought I made it clear, but I guess I didn't. I have updated the error section to show what is actually being displayed each time a page is loaded. I know all 5 are different errors, but all 5 repeat 5 times as now shown. :)
Sorry for the poor wording of the question

Comment: Ah yes, that makes more sense. Do you happen to have 5 widget areas on the one page that is loading when these errors happen? You may have a piece of code that is reverencing each of these pieces of code that has the error 5 times.